# Spring Boot and Generic component injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

Given the following functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Mapper<FROM, TO> {
    TO map(FROM from);
}
```

and the concrete classes that implement the functional interface (which are left out for brevity). Idea is to inject the generic class Mapper into another generic component called the ListMapper given below:

```
@Component
public final class ListMapper<FROM, TO> {
    private final Mapper<FROM, TO> mapper;

    public Mapper(Mapper<FROM, TO> mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public List<TO> mapList(final List<FROM> data) {
        if (data == null) return null;

        return data.stream()
                .map(mapper::map)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

ListMapper is injected into other components like so:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyClass1 {
    private final ListMapper<Foo1, Bar1> mapper;

    // ... rest is omitted for brevity
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyClass2 {
    private final ListMapper<Foo2, Bar2> mapper;
 
    // ...rest is omitted for brevity
}
```

However, doing so results in an error stating that the parameter mapper required a single bean, but three were found (as three different implementations of the Mapper interface are defined).

Is it possible to resolve this dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into issues because 'ListMapper' defined as Component and component by default is created with Singleton scope.

You might have to define 'ListMapper' beans as outlined in the article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation with Qualifier for getting the desired result.

In your case, you might have to remove Component annotation from 'ListMapper' and Assuming your mapper implementation looks like below:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("foobar")
public class FooBarMapper implements Mapper<Foo, Bar>{

  @Override
  public Bar map(final Foo foo) {
    return new Bar();
  }
}
```

Your bean definition can something like :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ListMapper<Foo, Bar> createFooBarListMapper(@Qualifier("foobar") FooBarMapper mapper) {
        return new ListMapper<Foo, Bar>(mapper);
    }
}
```